# Show that $x\sin(x)$ is not uniformly continuous on $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

For one of my homework problems, I'm supposed to show that $f(x)=x\sin(x)$ is not uniformly continuous on the real numbers, but this doesn't seem right to me.

I know that if a function is continuous on a closed and bounded interval then it is uniformly continuous on that interval. I also know that f is continuous on $\Bbb R$. It seems like a simple induction would show that f is UC on $\Bbb R$, so what's going on?

Please don't actually tell me how to solve the problem, but if you can tell me what I'm missing I would appreciate it.

Comment: Re: your induction comment, think about it this way: any continuous function on a closed and bounded interval is bounded. By induction, does it follow that any continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded? Of course not - *the bound depends on the interval*.

Comment: Ah. And in the same way, δ is different from interval to interval.

Comment: Indeed. :) ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Any continuous function on a compact interval is uniformly continuous.

This does not extend to $\mathbb{R}$ by induction, as $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact.

If it is uniformly continuous then for all $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x-y| < \delta$.

So, you need to show that there is some $\epsilon >0$ such that for all $\delta>0$ there is **some** $x,y$ with $|x-y| < \delta$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| \ge \epsilon$.

In your particular example, you can pick an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$.

Hint: Look at how quickly the function changes in the neighbourhood of a zero crossing.

Comment: My comment about induction comes from the fact that f is Uniformly continuous on every interval [-n, n], so an induction "should" show that it's true for every n.

Comment: @ZacharyF: Well, its **is** true for every $n$, but that doesn't mean it is true for $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @ZacharyF It is true for any $n$.  But $n$ is a real number.  And $x\sin x$ is UC on any closed and bounded interval.  But, for UC on the set of all real numbers, we need simply follow the definition provided herein by copper.hat.  And this is not possible, since we can always find a pair of as close as you like such that $|x\sin x|$ is greater than, say $1/2$.

Comment: A +1 for the nicely written post!

Comment: @Dr.MV: Thanks!

Comment: @copper.hat You're welcs!

Answer (score 1):

We shall assume $x \sin(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and reach a contradiction. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Since $x \sin(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ there is $\delta>0$ so that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we have

\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
| 2\pi \big(k +\frac{\delta}{2}\big) \sin\big(2\pi \big(k +\frac{\delta}{2}\big)\big) - 2\pi \big(k -\frac{\delta}{2}\big) \sin\big(2\pi \big(k -\frac{\delta}{2}\big)\big)| &= 4 \pi k \sin \big(\frac{\delta}{2}\big) \\
&<\varepsilon.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

However by the Archimedean property, we know that there is a positive integer $\hat{k}$ so that $4 \pi \hat{k} \sin \big(\frac{\delta}{2}\big)> \varepsilon$. This is a contradiction, and so the result is proved.

It should not be hard to see the above equality. Just do a little work to get from the left side to the right side of it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what happens with the derivative of this function for large $x$? What can we say when we try to apply the UC definition and look at $x=2\pi k$, $k\in \Bbb N$?